# How can I use maven profiling to a dependant

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-3, maven-profiles

Is there a way to use profile to a dependent class in maven profiling.

My problem is that, I have two projects under one parent.
**product-core-ws** and **product-core**.

**product-core-ws** is a *deplorable web service*.Now I want to create two profiles inside product-core like following

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>one</id>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fg</groupId>
                <artifactId>product-core-one</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>two</id>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fg</groupId>
                <artifactId>product-core-two</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and when I `clean install` the product-core-ws I need the dependency according to the given profile

For example if I use

> mvn clean install -P one

, I need the product-core-one inside my war file.

I know that I can do this directly in my **product-core-ws** POM file. But I don't want to use those in that POM. I want to use them through **product-core**.

Comment: "*deplorable web service*" > Don't be so hard on yourself! ;-)

Comment: @Duncan yes, when I install product-core-ws, either product-core-one or product-core-two should be there according to the profile I select

Answer (score 1):

In your parent POM, use profiles to set the value of a Maven property:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>one</id>
        <properties>
          <product.core.version>product-core-one</product.core.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>two</id>
        <properties>
          <product.core.version>product-core-two</product.core.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then use this property in the child module:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fg</groupId>
    <artifactId>${product.core.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: how should change my parent pom. are u saying I should create  profile just like I mentioned in the question????

Comment: what is the child are you refering, is it "product-core" or "product-core-ws"

Comment: @Ravindu `product-core-ws` is the child I'm referring to. Your question text is a little confusing (you seem to switch between which child you are talking about). But hopefully you see how to apply my advice to your problem.

Comment: no duncan, I want to do the profiling in the product-core. NOT product-core-ws

Comment: @Ravindu So you want to define profiles in `product-core` that affect the build that occurs in `product-core-ws`? If so, can you please explain if there are any dependencies between those two modules? I.e. does `product-core-ws` depend upon `product-core`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55957/discussion-between-ravindu-and-duncan).